# GDB source code - Access elf header from within source code to get properties

Tags: gdb, elf

I have a question regarding GDB source code which I want to modify in order to change the read/write access to memory. I have an elf file where the data is coded which means it needs to be transformed before reading and writing.
Therefore I have found out that the reading and write operation are performed in read_value_memory (gdb/valops.c) and target_write_memory (gdb/target.c).

Now I need to differentiate to only perform this in case the access it done to an shared object file.

The question is: How can I access the elf from GDB source code to access the elf header properties.

Comment: You say the data is coded (does that mean encrypted maybe?) within the ELF file, is it also coded in memory?  I ask because you mention target_write_memory, but obviously GDB never writes back to the original ELF, only ever to inferior memory.

Anyway, you might get what you need by looking at `memory_xfer_partial_1` and how `trust_readonly` is used.  This flag allows GDB to read read-only data directly from an ELF instead of inferior memory, but doing this requires GDB to get hold of the bfd object, which is what you want.  I think all mem read/write should pass through this function.

Comment: The data is coded (not really secure encrypted but similar). In the elf file inside the .data section. I guess I explained it wrong. I want to read from memory (as the memory_xfer_partial_1 is doing) but at this point I need to access the elf header and ideally also the prolog of the .text section to get some information regarding the *.so file. I assumed I need to use the BFD library for this kind of operation as this is the Interface from GDB to ELF right?

Comment: I think I'd start in `memory_xfer_partial`, in there you have an `if` where reads are handled in the if block, and writes in the else block.  You can use `const struct target_section *secp = target_section_by_addr (ops, memaddr);` to see if there's a section covering the address being accessed, and then `secp->the_bfd_section` to get the bfd section, and `secp->the_bfd_section->owner` to get the actual bfd.  From the bfd you should be able to find any contents of the ELF you need.

Comment: Perfect. That is extactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: One more related question: When I have the `struct target_section myTextSection` of the **.text** section and I want to have the address in memory. Where can I find this one? it looks like the `myTextSection.addr` and the `myTextSection.the_bfd_section.vma` are the same (low addresses) and related to the file not to memory addresses.

Comment: Take a look at `target_section_by_addr` and how it is used in `memory_xfer_partial_1` - the target section is looked up by memory address, and in `target_section_by_addr` the address is compared to the `.addr` and `.endaddr`, so I believe that these fields are memory addresses.  You are correct that the bfd_section `.vma` field is most likely the vma as specified in the ELF, so might be different in memory, but with the target_section I think you're OK.

Comment: Ok I see. I have issues getting the `.text` section from the bfd library. I got it working when I use `bfd_get_section_by_name(bfd, (char*)".text")` when I call afterwards `bfd_get_section_contents(bfd, textSection, &buffer, size)`. But I just want to directly access the memory address of the `.text` section. Is there an easy way to get that address?

Comment: it looks like the `.text` section has the flags 0x11B = (SEC_ALLOC, SEC_LOAD, SEC_READONLY, SEC_CODE, SEC_HAS_CONTENTS) but not `SEC_IN_MEMORY` so it can only be accessed directly from the file? I assumed it will be in memory as it is in a Segment of type `PT_LOAD`

Comment: SEC_IN_MEMORY doesn't mean what you think it does!  That flag is used within the linker/bfd when ELFs are being generated and indicates that the section contents only exist in memory, and are not being linked from some input bfd object.  That flag is not represented in the final ELF flags.  The SEC_LOAD flag represents the PT_LOAD ELF flag, and as you say, indicates that the section will have been loaded into the runtime image.

Comment: Ah ok thanks I see. So if I now have the Virtual address (textSection->vma) of my `.text` section. It is a virtual one inside of the inferior. Is there a method to access this memory from inside of GDB (I need a pointer to point to the start of the `.text` section.

Comment: From general gdb code you'd want `target_read_memory`, but, if you're working inside target.c functions then you can't call that as you might end up stuck in an infinite loop.  You probably need to look at the second half of `memory_xfer_partial_1`, first we check some caches, then finally we call `raw_memory_xfer_partial` to actually go and read memory - though you probably want your reads from `.text` to make use of the caches too, so check out the `dcache_read_memory_partial` call too.

Comment: Ok thanks I got that. Currently it is working with a combination of `bfd_get_section_by_name` followed by `bfd_get_section_contents`. But I would like to access the memory location directly without an additional buffer in between. Is there no possibility to somwhow *translate* the vma address to the real memory address?

Comment: Ok I guess I missunderstand it before. So it looks liek the `bfd_get_section_contents` gets the content from the file (not from memory). To get the content from the memory of the debugged application I used the `target_read_memory` as I did my changes not in there no looping problem occurs. Thanks for the help.